# Get parent of child node in angular material nested tree

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview, angular-material2

I'm working with angular material tree component. I am able to get details of my selected node. Now, what I want to achieve is to get the parent of the selected node or whole parent hierarchy. Do you know how can I achive this?

My tree looks like this in angular material docs:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/mrkvpbkolad?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

Comment: On which moment would you "get the parent of the selected node or whole parent hierarchy"?

Comment: @GCSDC when I click on particular node in the tree.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to get the whole parent hierarchy, at click on a child node, my solution is to use a recursive function:

```ts
onLeafNodeClick(node) {
  const ancestors = getAncestors(this.dataSource.data, node.name);
}

getAncestors(array, name) {
  if (typeof array !== 'undefined') {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].name === name) {
        return [array[i]];
      }
      const a = this.getAncestors(array[i].children, name);
      if (a !== null) {
        a.unshift(array[i]);
        return a;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This will return a new array, having at index `0` the root item, and at index `n-1` the child node that has been clicked.

**Working example**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r7rxyl-vwdlhy?file=app/tree-nested-overview-example.ts

The direct parent of the node will be:

```ts
const directParent = ancestors[ancestors.length - 2];
```

You can use this array to display breadcrumbs (`root/child_1/child_2`):

```ts
let breadcrumbs = '';
ancestors.forEach(ancestor => {
  breadcrumbs += `${ancestor.name}/`;
});
```

---

If you just want to get some attributes of the parent element (eg: *parent name*, *parent id*), my solution is to process the **original data** before assigning it to `mat-tree` **data source**. We can add a new property on each node, `parent`, which will be an object that stores the desired attributes of the parent element.

The code will be:

```ts
this.dataSource.data = this._processData(TREE_DATA);

_processData(data, parent = null) {
  data.forEach(item => {
    if (parent !== null) {
      item.parent = {name: parent.name};
    } else {
      item.parent = null;
    }
    if (item.children) {
      this._processData(item.children, item);
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

Example leaf node after data processing:

```ts
{
  name: "Apple", 
  parent: {
    name: "Fruit"
  }
}
```

**Working example**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r7rxyl?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge. This helped me.